# How to shift the values of a list to the left as much as possible?

Tags: python, list

Let's consider these two lists :

```
list1 = ['N/A', 'a', 'b', 'c']
list2 = [None, None, 'd', None, 'e']
```

1-) I need to shift their items to the left as long as there is a target value at the beginning but 2-) we should ignore the eventual targets that can be in the middle and finally 3-) we fill the replacements with a value from the end.

In a parallel universe, the function I need would be a method of the python's list: `list.lstrip(target_value, fill_value)`

I tried to make it real with the code below but it doesn't give the expected output for `list2` :

```
def lstrip(a_list, target_value=None, fill_value='Invalid'):
    if a_list[0] != target_value:
        return a_list
    else:
        result = []
        for element in a_list:
            if element != target_value:
                result.append(element)
        return result + [fill_value]*(len(a_list) - len(result))
```

The current outputs are :

```
print(lstrip(list1, 'N/A'))
['a', 'b', 'c', 'Invalid']

print(lstrip(list2))
['d', 'e', 'Invalid', 'Invalid', 'Invalid']
```

The second output should be `['d', None, 'e', 'Invalid', 'Invalid']`.

Do you guys have an idea how to fix my code ?

Comment: I don't think that the purpose of the program is to `strip`, it looks more a rearrangement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you could just find the index of the first non_target value and return the slice from that point on plus an array of fill values of the same length as the index:

```
list1 = ['N/A', 'a', 'b', 'c']
list2 = [None, None, 'd', None, 'e']


def lstrip(a_list, target_value=None, fill_value='Invalid'):
    i = next((i for i, v in enumerate(a_list) if v != target_value), len(a_list))
    return a_list[i:] + [fill_value] * i
    
    
print(lstrip(list1, 'N/A'))
# ['a', 'b', 'c', 'Invalid']

print(lstrip(list2))
# ['d', None, 'e', 'Invalid', 'Invalid']
```

Giving the length of the list as a default to `next()` covers the case where a list is all target values:

```
lstrip([None, None])
# ['Invalid', 'Invalid']
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue with your implementation is that the condition `if element != target_value:` continues to filter out `target_value`s even after an element that does not match the target value has been seen. You can fix this by adding a simple boolean flag for when a mismatch is found:

```
def lstrip(a_list, target_value=None, fill_value="Invalid"):
    if a_list[0] != target_value:
        return a_list
    else:
        seen_mismatch = False
        result = []
        for element in a_list:
            if element != target_value:
                seen_mismatch = True
            if seen_mismatch:
                result.append(element)
        return result + [fill_value] * (len(a_list) - len(result))
```

Here's an alternative implementation that makes use of partially consuming an iterator over the list. This also generalizes the function to work on empty lists and over other arbitrary [iterables](https://docs.python.org/3.12/glossary.html#term-iterable).

```
from collections.abc import Iterable, Iterator
from typing import TypeVar, Literal

_T = TypeVar("_T")


def lstrip(
    it: Iterable[_T],
    target_value: _T | None = None,
    fill_value: _T | Literal["Invalid"] = "Invalid",
) -> Iterator[_T]:
    it = iter(it)
    backfill = 0
    for elem in it:
        if elem == target_value:
            backfill += 1
        else:
            yield elem
            break

    yield from it
    yield from [fill_value] * backfill

>>> print(list(lstrip(list1, "N/A")))
['a', 'b', 'c', 'Invalid']


>>> print(list(lstrip(list2)))
['d', None, 'e', 'Invalid', 'Invalid']
```

Comment: Curious about the expected result of `lstrip([None, None])`